# How to stop Lucene Standard Analyzer removing special characters

Tags: java, lucene, lucene.net, examine, query-analyzer

I have been having some difficulty with Lucene and would appreciate any help.

I have a custom query which is manually written and parsed (this query) using QueryParser.Parse. I am using version LUCENE_29 and the StandardAnalyzer.

In my query I have a special character (colon) and need this to remain:

```
+(Name:"test\:word" OR Business:"test\:word hello")
```

The output after parsing the query text above is:

```
+(Name:"test word" OR Business:"test word hello")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, I tried passing an empty stop words collection to the StandardAnalyzer constructor but that has no effect it still strips out the colon.

Thank you.

Comment: You ask a good question. I had a similar problem with Lucene and found no way to resolve this issue. Lucene was retired on our website partly due to this issue.

Comment: @JohnH thanks for sharing this info!

Comment: FYI - `LUCENE_29` only tells us the version compatibility you have set, it doesn't tell us what lucene or lucene.net version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. StandardAnalyzer was specifically designed to remove special characters.

The answer is to use an Analyzer implementation that doesn't strip special characters (such as `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer`) or to build a custom analyzer based on existing tokenizers and filters to meet your needs.

Note that you would need to use `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer` to *index* your data with those special characters, otherwise they won't be available at query-time.

Comment: Hi, I have used the WhiteSpaceAnalyer and when using query.parse it results in : +(Name:test:word Name:"test:word hello") - This query works but I don't understand why the WhiteSpaceAnalyzer is stripping the quotation marks from the name field but leaving them on the Business field. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer` during index time? The analyzed data needs to be written to the index with the special characters otherwise they won't be available at query time.